# Image sprite as whole background of an element

Tags: css

As you can see below I'm using image sprites below which work fine. What I want to know is how do I use them as background of a `div` which won't have `width` and `height`.

Thanks

**WORKS FINE:**

```
.social_buttons
{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-image: url('../images/social.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.facebook
{
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.twitter
{
    background-position: -30px 0px;
}
.google
{
    background-position: -60px 0px;
}
```

**This shows all 3 the images as background and repeatedly.**

```
.mydiv
{
   background-image: url('../images/social.png');
   background-position: -60px 0px;
}
```

**This shows all 3 the images as background and just once.**

```
.mydiv
{
   background-image: url('../images/social.png');
   background-position: -60px 0px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: The element has to have the size of the image that's in the sprite for it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use percentages in some cases to apply backgrounds without determined size.

A button sprite:

```
 -------
|       |
|       | Default top half.
|       |
 -------
 -------
|       |
|       | :active bottom half.
|       |
 -------


button {
     background-image: url('#');
     background-size: 100% 200%;
}
button:active { background-position: bottom; }
```

As the sprite is split into two pieces evenly 200% will increase the image by double so only one half of the image is visible.

Here's an example that shows this. Change the height and width to see it working.

http://codepen.io/nickcolley/pen/KuLla

Answer (score 0):

You may have misunderstood the point of sprites... what you're trying to achieve can't be done with sprites, the background image should in this case be in a separate file, alone.

Comment: In that case, to send less HTTP requests, it should be made possible in future. I hope W3C guys implement it as well.

Comment: I don't see why W3C should take care of that. There are much more important matters. 1 or 2 http request more or less aren't an issue, and if we're talking about more than a few, then maybe you should consider not using as many background images...

Comment: If there is something to be improved then it is an "important matter" to me however, priority for importance might be lower compared to others in some cases so then deal with others first but don't ignore anything else. My opinion anyway.